# Create new class with dynamic name possibly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible in the js ES6 create class with different name?  like:

```
    'use strict'
    class SomeClass {
        someMethod(){
        }
    }
    ...
    var sClassName = "SomeClass";
    var variableClass = new Class(sClassName)();
    variableClass.someMethod();
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you want this?

Comment: Our software trying uses V8 as build in engine. This is not related with web develop. And that pattern would be very handy for our tasks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `eval`:

```
'use strict'
class SomeClass {
    someMethod(){
    }
}
...
var sClassName = "SomeClass";
var variableClass = eval("new " + sClassName+ "()");

variableClass.someMethod();
```

If you wish to avoid `eval`, you might be able to use something like this:

```
var classByCase = {
   caseA: SomeClass,
   caseB: SomeOtherClass
};
var currentCase = 'caseA';
var variableClass = new classByCase[currentCase]();
```

Comment: Eval is perfect for our tasks. This requires a few specific things.Thank you !